# Using tf.keras.model.predict inside tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Multiply
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

print(tf.__version__) # 2.1.1

def build_model():
    inputs = Input(shape=(42,))
    x = Multiply()([inputs, inputs])

    return Model(inputs, x)

x = tf.constant(3, shape=(1, 42), dtype='float32')

model = build_model()
print(model.predict(x)) # works fine

@tf.function
def f(x):
    x += 5
    return model.predict(x) # throws ValueError

print(f(x))
```

Running this simple peice of code produces

```
    ValueError: When using data tensors as input to a model, you should specify the `steps` argument.
```

when invoking `model.predict`, located inside the `@tf.function`.

Why does it happen? Should I not use `model.predict` inside the `@tf.function`? Or do it elsehow?

If I replace the `model.predict(input)` to just `model(input)`, everything works fine.
Also, if I add the `steps=1` argument as the error suggests, there's another error

```
    ValueError: Unknown graph. Aborting.
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think the TF version > 2.3 give the explanation in it's output error, I run your code with TF 2.3.1 which give the error:

```
RuntimeError: Detected a call to `Model.predict` inside a `tf.function`. 
`Model.predict is a high-level endpoint that manages its own `tf.function`. 
Please move the call to `Model.predict` outside of all enclosing `tf.function`s. 
Note that you can call a `Model` directly on `Tensor`s inside a `tf.function` like: `model(x)`.
```